# SQL count with having

Tags: sql, t-sql

CustomerID, is unique.

What result is given with this question?

```
SELECT personalnumber, 
   Amount = Count(CustomerID), 
FROM   Customer
GROUP  BY personalnumber 
HAVING Count(CustomerID) > 100
```

What does it mean that
having count(CustomerID) > 100?? Is it that the CustomerID has to be above 100?

Comment: That is invalid standard SQL. Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using?  Please add the tag for the database product you are using

Comment: This is a question I got from school, I was just supposed to tell them what type of result that is given with this query. Why is it invalid? And by the way how would you interpret the whole query?

Comment: The part `Amount = ...` is invalid in (standard) SQL. That would only be valid SQL, if there was a column `amount`. In that case that would be a boolean expression comparing the column `amount` to the result of the `count()` function

Comment: In standard SQL you'd write `Count(CustomerID) AS Amount` instead of `Amount = Count(CustomerID)`. I suggest you only use the standard compliant syntax. They should at least point this out when teaching vendor specific syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have been given two answers, but now you've edited your request without accepting one of them. So I guess you haven't understood the answers given so far.

```
GROUP BY personalnumber
```

means that you want one result row per `personalnumber`. All records for one `personalnumber` get aggregated to a single row.

```
Count(CustomerID)
```

counts all occurrences where `CustomerID` is not null.

```
HAVING Count(CustomerID) > 100
```

limits your result to those `personalnumber` that have more than 100 records with a `CustomerID`.

As this is the `Customer` table, we must assume that `CustomerID` is the table's ID, uniquely identifying a record, and it can't be null.

So this should better be written as

```
HAVING Count(*) > 100
```

meaning just the same: limit the result to those `personalnumber` that occur in more than 100 records. (`Count(*)` means: count rows.)

Comment: Thank you so much! You explained it perfectly! I’m new to stackoverflow and forgot how to accept the answer. But thanks now I understand it even more than I did before!

Answer (score 1):

It means that the `personalnumber` has more than 100 associated `CustomerID`'s

Answer (score 1):

It means that the `personalnumber`s returned by the query are on more than 100 rows where `CustomerId` is not null.

If the code just wanted to count rows, I would recommend:

```
having count(*) > 100
```

This doesn't depend on the nullability of a column.

If `customerid` could be duplicated and you wanted to check for 100 *different* values, then you would use:

```
having count(distinct CustomerId) > 100
```

If you were filtering on `CustomerId`, you would use a `where` clause before the `group by`.

Comment: Thank you!! I finally get it. How would you interpret the whole query?